# Python - splitting data as columns in csv file

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I have data in a csv file that looks like that is imported as this.

```
import csv

with open('Half-life.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f))
```

the data will come out as this to where it prints out the rows like `data[0] = ['10', '2', '2']` and so on.

What i'm wanting though is to retrieve the data as columns in instead of rows, to where in this case, there are 3 columns.

Comment: can you install pandas? `pandas.read_csv('Half-life.csv')` would do this and infer proper types for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create three separate lists, and then append to each using [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-contents).

```
import csv

c1 = []
c2 = []
c3 = []
with open('Half-life.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        c1.append(row[0])
        c2.append(row[1])
        c3.append(row[2])
```

Comment: The ```for``` loop could be replaced with ```columns = zip(*reader)```.

Answer (score 6):

A little more automatic and flexible version of [Alexander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37686390/1394393):

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list)
with open('Half-life.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            columns[i].append(row[i])
# Following line is only necessary if you want a key error for invalid column numbers
columns = dict(columns)
```

You could also modify this to use column headers instead of column numbers.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list)
with open('Half-life.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    headers = next(reader)
    column_nums = range(len(headers)) # Do NOT change to xrange
    for row in reader:
        for i in column_nums:
            columns[headers[i]].append(row[i])
# Following line is only necessary if you want a key error for invalid column names
columns = dict(columns)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option, if you have `numpy` installed, you can use `loadtxt` to read a csv file into a numpy array. You can then transpose the array if you want more columns than rows (I wasn't quite clear on how you wanted the data to look). For example:

```
import numpy as np
# Load data
data = np.loadtxt('csv_file.csv', delimiter=',')
# Transpose data if needs be
data = np.transpose(data)
```