# opening, readind and splitting file (python)

Tags: python

> i need to open the excel file called conc_H.csv and split the 2 columns which are named "Time" and "conc" and i need to append the contents of the 2 columns into the newly created lists called time and conc. however when i run this code there is no output.

```
conc_file = open('conc_H.csv')
time = []
conc = []

for i, line in enumerate(conc_file.readlines()):
    if (i > 0):
        tmp = line.split("//")  
        time.append(float(tmp[0]))
        conc.append(float(tmp[1]))

print(conc)
```

Comment: Is it an excel file or a csv file without metadata? In any case, there are abstractions in the standard library to read these files - use them.

Comment: Also we can't help you without a sample file.

Comment: It's easier by using [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-contents). Check this solution for better explanation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37686390/10473393

Comment: There is probably a problem with your `line.split("//")`... In a csv file, the inner line split is probably "," or ";"

Comment: it is a csv file and i'm only allowed to change line 1, "("//") and  "temp = " so there error is somewhere there.